# Address a specific looped input with jQuery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have HTML code looped with another jQuery. There is an input which looped too. I want to address it in jQuery Ajax... but only the first input works... and the same values are printed for the rest in the console.

```js
success: function (r) {
        var posts = JSON.parse(r)
        $.each(posts, function (index) {
            $('.timelineposts').html(
                $('.timelineposts').html() + '<blockquote><p>' + posts[index].PostBody + '</p><footer>Posted by ' + posts[index].PostedBy + ' on ' + posts[index].PostDate + '<button class="btn btn-default" data-id="' + posts[index].PostId + '" type="button" style="color:#eb3b60;background-image:url(&quot;none&quot;);background-color:transparent;"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart" data-aos="flip-right"></i><span> ' + posts[index].Likes + ' Likes</span></button><button class="btn btn-default comment" type="button" data-postid="' + posts[index].PostId + '" style="color:#eb3b60;background-image:url(&quot;none&quot;);background-color:transparent;"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-flash" style="color:#f9d616;"></i><span style="color:#f9d616;"> Comments</span></button></footer><input type="text" class="c"><button  comment-postid="' + posts[index].PostId + '">comment</button></blockquote>'
            )


/////////////////////ajax/////////////////////////

            $('[comment-postid]').click(function () {
                var buttonid = $(this).attr('comment-postid');
                var value = $('.c').val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "api/comments1?id=" + buttonid,
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    data: '{ "commentBody": "' + value + '"}',
                    success: function (r) {
                        //var res = JSON.parse(r)
                        console.log(buttonid);
                        console.log(value);
                        value = "";
                        buttonid = "";


                    },
                    error: function (r) {
                        console.log("ddd")
                    }
                });
            })
        })
```

Comment: how is the inner ajax associated with the outer ajax?

Comment: With the comment-postid

Comment: why can't you put the inner ajax outside the outer ajax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out!
I named each class with a different postid value...so when the loop iterates, each post will have anew class, so I address it in the ajax!

```
<input type="text" class="'+posts[index].PostId+'" >
```

and in ajax: `var buttonid = $(this).attr('comment-postid');
            var v=$('.'+buttonid).val();`

Comment: Might be better just to use an ID rather than a class if those PostIds are unique...